# Spring JPA transaction in clustered environment

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, cluster-computing, jta

I use `Spring-JPA` in my application. I use container managed option for `EntityManager` and use `JTA` transaction manager.

this `Java EE` application is deployed in `JBoss` clustered environment, will the isolation of transactions be taken care of?

In other words, will two different requests on different JBoss nodes and two different request processed on one JBoss node behave differently in isolation perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction isolation behaviour and limitations are dependent on the database provider. Now if your using Oracle RAC , I haven't seen issues but on a MYSQL instance this is an issue.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to confirm: Does it mean JTA make use of the database capabilities to ensure transaction characteristics ?

Comment: Yes that is correct, the local or global transaction management will be coordinated using JTA.